# Xpath - Find specific element, print all elements of that node

Tags: xpath, xml-namespaces, xmllint

Given the following Xpath to an element

```
/std:Batch/BatchSection/ContractPartner/Contractor/Contract/contractNumber
```

How can I print out all subelements of the node Contract
where sequenceNumber= 12345?

I tried

```
xmllint --xpath "string(/std:Batch/BatchSection/ContractPartner/Contractor/Contract/contractNumber[contractNumber='12345'])" test.xml
```

However, that is an invalid XPath expression. How to fix that?

Example input:

```
<std:Batch xmlns:std="http://www.test.com/contractBatch" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <year>2020</year>
  <batchType>3</batchType>
  <runDate>2020-04-11</runDate>
  <text>Datatest</text>
  <jobInfo>Test</jobInfo>
  <BatchSection>
    <addedAtDate>2020-04-11</addedAtDate>
    <ContractPartner>
      <contractDealerAG>44444</contractDealerAG>
      <contractorType/>
      <isoCountry>NL</isoCountry>
      <language>EN</language>
      <Contractor>
        <contractor>44444</contractor>
        <Contract>
          <contractor>44444</contractor>
          <sequenceNumber>12345</sequenceNumber>
          <info1>abcd</info1>
        </Contract>
      </Contractor>
    </ContractPartner>
  </BatchSection>
</std:Batch>
```

Desired output (where sequenceNumber=12345):

```
    <Contract>
      <contractor>44444</contractor>
      <sequenceNumber>12345</sequenceNumber>
      <info1>abcd</info1>
   </Contract>
```

Comment: Edited my post accordingly

Comment: Now it is valid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to deal with the dreaded namespaces, unfortunately... Try it like this:

```
xmllint --xpath "//*[local-name()='Contract'] [.//*[local-name()='sequenceNumber'][./text()='12345']]" test.xml
```

and see if it works.

Comment: That's exactly what I need, works perfectly. Thanks! - By dealing with namespaces you mean the necessity of putting the prefix local-name() in front of every element?

Comment: @royskatt There's much more to namespaces than just that, unfortunately. You'll have to look it up (here, for example:  https://courses.ischool.berkeley.edu/i290-8/s04/lectures/2/allslides.html).

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you mean sequenceNumber, as per xml example, if that's the case then you may need to do something like this to return the node Contract:

```
xmllint --xpath "//sequenceNumber[.="12345"]/.." test.xml
```